# Posts, comments, replies, and likes database schema

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a site where a users can comment on posts or reply to a comment. The user can also like replies or comments. Replies are not nested, so a reply doesn't have a reply. However, there is another field called `reply_to` within the reply table. Here's my current schema:

```
Comment
id
user (foreign key)
post (foreign key)
comment

Reply
id
user (foreign key)
comment (foreign key)
reply

CommentLike (Table that shows which user liked which comments)
id
comment (foreign key)
user (foreign key)
like (1 = likes, 0 = dislikes)

ReplyLike (Table that shows which user liked which replies)
id
reply (foreign key)
user (foreign key)
like (1 = likes, 0 = dislikes)
```

Does this seem like a good schema to use, or is there a better way to create this sort of structure?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can download and have a look at StackOverflow database schema.

Answer (score 1):

Your question would be easier to read, if you included the references for your foreign keys.

I'm guessing that `user (foreign key)` refers to field `id` in `users` table (not displayed), and similarly with `post`.

With those two, as well as with the other foreign keys, I would attach `_id` to the name, so that it's clear they are ids and not names.

You don't specify primary keys. Did you already designate `id` in each table to be the primary key, and has auto-increment? If not, make sure you do.

Other than that, I think it's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a perfectly good "natural" key, don't include an `id`.  For example, for `Replies`, `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, comment_id)` is good.  It looks like all 4 tables could follow this guideline.

Where are the `Users` and other tables?  It would be better to provide `CREATE TABLE` than use verbal hand-waving.  You will need to do that eventually, anyway.

Comment: Having `(user_id,comment_id)` as the PK of `Replies` would only allow a single reply per user, for each comment - usually this is not how discussion forums with posts, comments, and replies works. Such a composite PK is only a good idea for the "Likes" tables, which don't tend to allow multiple likes.

Comment: @WillemRenzema - perhaps it does work for the other tables?  (I am unclear on what each table represents -- the difference between a "comment" and a "reply", etc.